# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"В последние годы страна стала ускоренными темпами развивать солнечную энергетику(,) и в первую очередь активизировала строительство солнечных коллекторов".

Нужна ли здесь запятая?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая не нужна: предложение простое. Подлежащее -"страна", сказуемые - "стала развивать"  и "активизировала"

Answer (score 1):

Союз "и" здесь вполне равнозначен союзу  "и притом", значит, в данном случае мы имеем присоединительную конструкцию, следовательно, запятая нужна.

Comment: Вот именно так я и думала

Answer (score 0):

мне кажется надо отделить запятыми оборот " в первую очередь".